# Why do some packages ship binaries in /usr/lib?

Tags: software-installation

I was recently trying to install Go, and got tripped up by the fact that the package I was using puts the binaries in `/usr/lib/go-1.9/bin/`.

I looked into this a bit more, and discovered* that there are 212 packages available to me that put something in `/usr/lib/*/bin/`. Why would packages put binaries here and not in `/usr/bin`?

*via `apt-file search -xl '/usr/lib/[^/]*/bin/' | wc -l`

Answer (score 5):

Typically, those would be commands that are not meant to be called directly by the user. `/usr/libexec` used to be more common for that.